# StimulusJS How to set an instance variable on connect

Tags: javascript, stimulusjs

I am trying to get into stimulusJS

```
import { Controller } from 'stimulus'

export default class extends Controller {

  static targets = [
    'foo',
  ]

  connect() {
    const fooValue = this.fooTarget.value
    console.log(this.fooValue) // 7
    this.someFunction()
  }

  someFunction(){
    console.log(this.fooValue) // undefined
  }

}
```

I want to be able to get this value on connect as I want to know if it has changed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code declares `const` variable within the scope of `connect()` function. But you should use `this` (*Stimulus Controller*) property instead:

```
...
  connect() {
    this.fooValue = this.fooTarget.value
...
```